# How to truncate a date in .net?

Tags: .net

Besides the DateTime ctor (new DateTime(year, month, day)) , is there any other way to truncate a date?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

Returns just the date component (the time is midnight).

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Also, ToString() is overloaded in DateTime, you can pass a few dozen formatting options to it.

See:
http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/demos/datetimeformats.aspx

Comment: I'm disappointed in you Jon.  I've come to expect better from you!  Hey - check out my answer to the Asynchronous Linq question.  Pretty sweet.

Comment: Meh, I just misunderstood what he was asking for. I thought he wanted to know how to format its output to not contain time info, not that he wanted a date object with no time.

Comment: Jon - saw your comment on the other answer.  You're forgiven.  I hate when people do that.