# How to get date part from datetime?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

> Duplicate: [How to truncate a date in
>   .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252493/how-to-truncate-a-date-in-net/252494#252494)

I have datetime field containing '4/1/2009 8:00:00AM'. I want to get '4/1/2009' without the time.

Comment: Do you want to do it in VB, or in SQL? Which SQL server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of the datetime field (if you need to do this on the client)

Answer (score 3):

DateTime.Date will give you just the date portion of the datetime if you want to pass it around your application

Answer (score 3):

If you are inside of .NET as it appears that you are based on the tags

```
dim myDate as DateTime = DateTime.Parse('4/1/2009 8:00:00AM')
dim myDesiredValue as String = myDate.ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is C# (yeah - I know you want VB) but given that none of the following uses anything other than DataTime then it should give you want you want...

```
        string foo = "4/1/2009 8:00:00AM";
        DateTime bar = DateTime.Parse(foo);
        string output = bar.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database server, but in sql server I normally use this in my sql query:

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST([MyDateTimeColumn] AS float)) AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT(varchar,mydate,101)

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(DATE, dateFieldName)
```